# Importing complex XML file into a flat object

Tags: c#, linq, xml

I am trying to parse xml file using `XDocument`, basically, I have to select xml element based on requirement and convert into list model.

Below is sample code I am using right now, is there any better way to code or any best practice?

Please suggest.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"F:\temp\123.xml");
        var enrollments = PopulateEnrollment(doc);
        var companies = PopulateEmployerTable(doc);
        var plans = PopulatePlan(doc);


    }

    private static List<planTable> PopulatePlan(XDocument doc)
    {
        string planCode = string.Empty;

        var plans = doc.Root
              .Elements("Companies").Elements("Company").Elements("Plans").Elements("Plan")
              .Select(
              x => new planTable
              {
                  TpaId = "MyTPA",
                  PlanName = (string)x.Element("PlanName"),
                  Benefit = (string)x.Element("Benefit"),
                  Code = GetPlanCode(x),
                  BenefitPlanStartDate = GetPlanCode(x).Equals("HSA") ? "20000101" : (string)x.Element("StartDate"),
                  BenefitPlanEndDate = GetPlanCode(x).Equals("HSA") ? "20993101" : (string)x.Element("EndDate"),
                  Type = (string)x.Element("Type"),
                  PlanId = (string)x.Element("CompanyIdentifier"),
                  PartnerPlanID = (string)x.Element("PlanMapping").Element("PartnerPlanId1"),
                  TPAEmployerId = (string)x.Parent.Parent.Element("Identifier"),
                  TPASystemPlanId = (string)x.Element("PlanIdentifier")
              })
              .ToList();

        return plans;
    }


    private static string GetPlanCode(XElement x)
    {
        if ((string)x.Element("PlanMapping").Element("PlanMap") != null)
        {
            return (string)x.Element("PlanMapping").Element("PlanMap").Value;
        }
        return (string)x.Element("Type").Value;
    }



    private static List<EnrollmentTable> PopulateEnrollment(XDocument doc)
    {
        var enrollmentTable = doc.Descendants("Enrollment")
             .Select(
             x => new EnrollmentTable
             {
                 TpaId = "MyCompany",
                 EmployeeId = (string)x.Parent.Element("ExternalEmployeeId"),
                 CoverageLevel = (string)x.Element("CoverageLevel"),
                 PlanStartDate = (string)x.Element("PlanStarts"),
                 PlanEndDate = (string)x.Element("PlanEnds"),
                 CreatedDate = (string)x.Element("Created"),
                 LastModifiedDate = (string)x.Element("LastModified"),
                 PlanCode = (string)x.Element("PlanMapping").Element("PlanMap"),
                 CoverageStartDate = (string)x.Element("CafeteriaData") != null ? (string)x.Element("CafeteriaData").Element("OriginalStartDate") : (string)x.Element("HSAData").Element("EmployeeStartDate"),
                 CoverageEndDate = (string)x.Element("EndDate"),
                 CurrentElection = (string)x.Element("CafeteriaData") != null ? (string)x.Element("CafeteriaData").Element("CurrentElection") : null,
                 PayFrequency = (string)x.Element("CafeteriaData") != null ? (string)x.Element("CafeteriaData").Element("PayPeriods") : null,
                 StartReason = (string)x.Element("StartReason"),
                 PerPayAmount = (string)x.Element("CafeteriaData") != null ? (string)x.Element("CafeteriaData").Element("PerPayAmount") : (string)x.Element("HSAData").Element("PerPayAmount"),
                 EmployerPerPayAmount = (string)x.Element("CafeteriaData") != null ? (string)x.Element("CafeteriaData").Element("EmployerPerPayAmount") : (string)x.Element("HSAData").Element("EmployerPerPayAmount"),
                 AnnualAmount = (string)x.Element("CafeteriaData") != null ? (string)x.Element("CafeteriaData").Element("AnnualAmount") : (string)x.Element("HSAData").Element("YearlyEmployeeAmount"),
                 EmployerAnnualAmount = (string)x.Element("CafeteriaData") != null ? (string)x.Element("CafeteriaData").Element("EmployerAnnualAmount") : (string)x.Element("HSAData").Element("YearlyEmployerAmount")

             })
             .ToList();

        return enrollmentTable;
    }


    private static List<EmployerTable> PopulateEmployerTable(XDocument doc)
    {
        var employers = doc.Root
              .Elements("Companies").Elements("Company")
              .Select(
              x => new EmployerTable
              {
                  TpaId = "MyCompany",
                  SenderId = "EmpNav",
                  Ein = (string)x.Element("TaxID"),
                  Name = (string)x.Element("Name"),
                  State = (string)x.Element("State"),
                  CrossoverDate = (string)System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(),
                  XOFileName = "MyCompany.xml",
                  Status = "MyStatus",
                  LastProcessedDate = (string)System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(),
                  TPAEmployerId = (string)x.Element("Identifier"),
                  IsLatest = true,
                  HasMultiplePayrollGroups = HasMultiplePayrollGroup(x)

              })
              .ToList();

        return employers;
    }

    private static bool HasMultiplePayrollGroup(XElement x)
    {
        bool hasMultiplePayrollGrpup = false;

        if ((string)x.Element("PayrollGroups").Element("PayrollGroup") != null)
        {
            int count = x.Elements("PayrollGroups")
                .Elements("PayrollGroup")
                .Count();
            if (count > 1)
                hasMultiplePayrollGrpup = true;
        }
        return hasMultiplePayrollGrpup;


    }

    class EmployerTable
    {
        public string TpaId { get; set; }
        public string SenderId { get; set; }
        public string Ein { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string CrossoverDate { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string LastProcessedDate { get; set; }
        public string TPAEmployerId { get; set; }
        public bool HasMultiplePayrollGroups { get; set; }
        public string XOFileName { get; set; }
        public bool IsLatest { get; set; }
    }

    class planTable
    {
        public string TpaId { get; set; }
        public string PlanName { get; set; }
        public string Benefit { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string BenefitPlanStartDate { get; set; }
        public string BenefitPlanEndDate { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string PlanId { get; set; }
        public string PartnerPlanID { get; set; }
        public string TPAEmployerId { get; set; }
        public string TPASystemPlanId { get; set; }
        public bool isLatest { get; set; }

    }

    class EnrollmentTable
    {
        public string TpaId { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string CoverageLevel { get; set; }
        public string PlanStartDate { get; set; }
        public string PlanEndDate { get; set; }
        public string CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public string LastModifiedDate { get; set; }
        public string PlanCode { get; set; }
        public string ShortCode { get; set; }
        public string TpaEmployerId { get; set; }
        public string CoverageStartDate { get; set; }
        public string PerPayAmount { get; set; }
        public string EmployerPerPayAmount { get; set; }
        public string AnnualAmount { get; set; }
        public string EmployerAnnualAmount { get; set; }
        public string CoverageEndDate { get; set; }
        public string CurrentElection { get; set; }
        public string PayFrequency { get; set; }
        public string StartReason { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public bool isLatest { get; set; }


    }
}
}
```

Sample XML File

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Data xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
      <Header>
        <Disclaimer>Data API v0.2</Disclaimer>
        <ExchangeName>MyCompany FLEX</ExchangeName>
        <VendorName>MyCompany</VendorName>
        <VendorCode />
        <TransmissionCode />
        <RunDate>2017-10-04T02:31:25.4327731-04:00</RunDate>
        <EnrollmentType>Current</EnrollmentType>
      </Header>
      <Companies>
        <Company>
          <Identifier>TEST1_FLEX</Identifier>
          <Name>Dunder Mifflin</Name>
          <TaxID>12-123456789</TaxID>
          <Address1>1725 Slough Avenue</Address1>
          <Address2 />
          <City>Scranton</City>
          <State>PA</State>
          <ZIP>77070</ZIP>
          <VoiceNumber />
          <Contacts>
            <Contact>
              <Name>Kathy</Name>
              <Phone>(301) 522-4100</Phone>
              <Email>kcummings@samplecompany.com</Email>
            </Contact>
            <Contact>
              <Name>Meredith Grey</Name>
              <Phone>(301) 854-7716</Phone>
              <Email>Meredith@email.demo</Email>
            </Contact>
            <Contact>
              <Name>Michael McDonald</Name>
              <Phone>(555) 334-0909</Phone>
              <Email>McDonald Insurance Group</Email>
            </Contact>
            <Contact>
              <Name>Ms K</Name>
              <Phone>(281) 377-3939</Phone>
              <Email />
            </Contact>
          </Contacts>
          <Classes>
            <Class>
              <Name>admin</Name>
            </Class>
            <Class>
              <Name>All Full Time Employees</Name>
            </Class>
            <Class>
              <Name>Full Time / Salaried</Name>
            </Class>
            <Class>
              <Name>Officers</Name>
            </Class>
            <Class>
              <Name>Part Time / Hourly</Name>
            </Class>
            <Class>
              <Name>Union</Name>
            </Class>
          </Classes>
          <Departments>
            <Department>
              <Name>Accounting</Name>
            </Department>
            <Department>
              <Name>Customer Service</Name>
            </Department>
            <Department>
              <Name>Operations</Name>
            </Department>
            <Department>
              <Name>Sales</Name>
            </Department>
          </Departments>
          <Divisions>
            <Division>
              <Name>Bel Air</Name>
            </Division>
            <Division>
              <Name>Gaithersburg/Corp</Name>
            </Division>
            <Division>
              <Name>Hagerstown/Field</Name>
            </Division>
          </Divisions>
          <Offices>
            <Office>
              <Name>Bel Air</Name>
              <Address1>123 Test Lane</Address1>
              <Address2 />
              <City>Bel Air</City>
              <State>MD</State>
              <ZIP>21740</ZIP>
            </Office>
            <Office>
              <Name>Gaithersburg</Name>
              <Address1>1 Technology Drive</Address1>
              <Address2>Suite 500</Address2>
              <City>Rockville</City>
              <State>MD</State>
              <ZIP>20877</ZIP>
            </Office>
            <Office>
              <Name>Hagerstown</Name>
              <Address1>20 Data Drive</Address1>
              <Address2 />
              <City>Germantown</City>
              <State>MD</State>
              <ZIP>20880</ZIP>
            </Office>
          </Offices>
          <BusinessUnits>
            <BusinessUnit>
              <Name>Accounting</Name>
              <TaxID>12-5555555</TaxID>
            </BusinessUnit>
            <BusinessUnit>
              <Name>Customer Service</Name>
              <TaxID>12-0000912</TaxID>
            </BusinessUnit>
            <BusinessUnit>
              <Name>Operations</Name>
              <TaxID>11-0000021</TaxID>
            </BusinessUnit>
            <BusinessUnit>
              <Name>Sales</Name>
              <TaxID>14-0000031</TaxID>
            </BusinessUnit>
          </BusinessUnits>
          <PayrollGroups>
            <PayrollGroup>
              <Name>Executive payroll</Name>
              <PayFrequency>24</PayFrequency>
            </PayrollGroup>
            <PayrollGroup>
              <Name>Medical Spending Account BW26</Name>
              <PayFrequency>26</PayFrequency>
            </PayrollGroup>
            <PayrollGroup>
              <Name>Sample Payroll BW24</Name>
              <PayFrequency>24</PayFrequency>
            </PayrollGroup>
            <PayrollGroup>
              <Name>test</Name>
              <PayFrequency>24</PayFrequency>
            </PayrollGroup>
          </PayrollGroups>
          <Plans>
            <Plan>
              <CompanyIdentifier>TEST1_FLEX</CompanyIdentifier>
              <Carrier />
              <PlanName>Medical Flexible Spending Account 2014</PlanName>
              <Benefit>Flexible Spending Account</Benefit>
              <Type>Flexible Spending Account</Type>
              <StartDate>2014-01-01T00:00:00</StartDate>
              <EndDate>2014-12-31T00:00:00</EndDate>
              <CarrierPlanCode />
              <CarrierPlanTypeCode />
              <PolicyNumber>123456</PolicyNumber>
              <IsIssueAgePlan>false</IsIssueAgePlan>
              <IsPostTax>false</IsPostTax>
              <PlanMapping />
              <IsSelfBill xsi:nil="true" />
              <IsSelfFunded>false</IsSelfFunded>
              <PlanIdentifier>2881cce8-c4d5-4db6-9723-f45f3fba991f</PlanIdentifier>
            </Plan>
            <Plan>
              <CompanyIdentifier>TEST1_FLEX</CompanyIdentifier>
              <Carrier>HSA Bank</Carrier>
              <PlanName>HSA 2015</PlanName>
              <Benefit>Consumer Directed Health</Benefit>
              <Type>Healthcare Savings Account</Type>
              <StartDate>2015-01-01T00:00:00</StartDate>
              <EndDate>2015-12-31T00:00:00</EndDate>
              <CarrierPlanCode />
              <CarrierPlanTypeCode />
              <PolicyNumber />
              <IsIssueAgePlan>false</IsIssueAgePlan>
              <IsPostTax>false</IsPostTax>
              <PlanMapping />
              <IsSelfBill xsi:nil="true" />
              <IsSelfFunded>false</IsSelfFunded>
              <PlanIdentifier>05aed29a-d788-4872-b500-8a84fe3d9b1f</PlanIdentifier>
            </Plan>
            <Plan>
              <CompanyIdentifier>TEST1_FLEX</CompanyIdentifier>
              <Carrier />
              <PlanName>Dependent Spending Account 2016</PlanName>
              <Benefit>Dependent Care Spending Account</Benefit>
              <Type>Dependent Care Spending Account</Type>
              <StartDate>2016-01-01T00:00:00</StartDate>
              <EndDate>2016-12-31T00:00:00</EndDate>
              <CarrierPlanCode />
              <CarrierPlanTypeCode />
              <PolicyNumber />
              <IsIssueAgePlan>false</IsIssueAgePlan>
              <IsPostTax>false</IsPostTax>
              <PlanMapping />
              <IsSelfBill xsi:nil="true" />
              <IsSelfFunded>false</IsSelfFunded>
              <PlanIdentifier>c84a0658-f071-421a-b99f-e98c5e0e3f32</PlanIdentifier>
            </Plan>
            <Plan>
              <CompanyIdentifier>TEST1_FLEX</CompanyIdentifier>
              <Carrier />
              <PlanName>Flexible Spending Account 2016</PlanName>
              <Benefit>Flexible Spending Account</Benefit>
              <Type>Flexible Spending Account</Type>
              <StartDate>2016-01-01T00:00:00</StartDate>
              <EndDate>2016-12-31T00:00:00</EndDate>
              <CarrierPlanCode />
              <CarrierPlanTypeCode />
              <PolicyNumber>123456</PolicyNumber>
              <IsIssueAgePlan>false</IsIssueAgePlan>
              <IsPostTax>false</IsPostTax>
              <PlanMapping />
              <IsSelfBill xsi:nil="true" />
              <IsSelfFunded>false</IsSelfFunded>
              <PlanIdentifier>3be6447a-dbcf-4a52-bf73-880c0a85e8dc</PlanIdentifier>
            </Plan>
            <Plan>
              <CompanyIdentifier>TEST1_FLEX</CompanyIdentifier>
              <Carrier>Unspecified Carrier</Carrier>
              <PlanName>HRA</PlanName>
              <Benefit>Consumer Directed Health</Benefit>
              <Type>Healthcare Reimbursement Account</Type>
              <StartDate>2016-01-01T00:00:00</StartDate>
              <EndDate>2016-12-31T00:00:00</EndDate>
              <CarrierPlanCode />
              <CarrierPlanTypeCode />
              <PolicyNumber />
              <IsIssueAgePlan>false</IsIssueAgePlan>
              <IsPostTax>false</IsPostTax>
              <PlanMapping />
              <IsSelfBill xsi:nil="true" />
              <IsSelfFunded>false</IsSelfFunded>
              <PlanIdentifier>a83b7e3e-88e2-417c-911f-6418d03d72f3</PlanIdentifier>
            </Plan>
            <Plan>
              <CompanyIdentifier>TEST1_FLEX</CompanyIdentifier>
              <Carrier>HSA Bank</Carrier>
              <PlanName>HSA 2016</PlanName>
              <Benefit>Consumer Directed Health</Benefit>
              <Type>Healthcare Savings Account</Type>
              <StartDate>2016-01-01T00:00:00</StartDate>
              <EndDate>2016-12-31T00:00:00</EndDate>
              <CarrierPlanCode />
              <CarrierPlanTypeCode />
              <PolicyNumber />
              <IsIssueAgePlan>false</IsIssueAgePlan>
              <IsPostTax>false</IsPostTax>
              <PlanMapping />
              <IsSelfBill xsi:nil="true" />
              <IsSelfFunded>false</IsSelfFunded>
              <PlanIdentifier>d0d5fafe-98ae-4a8a-ae50-179cbb457860</PlanIdentifier>
            </Plan>
            <Plan>
              <CompanyIdentifier>TEST1_FLEX</CompanyIdentifier>
              <Carrier />
              <PlanName>Parking Reimbursement (2016)</PlanName>
              <Benefit>Parking Reimbursement</Benefit>
              <Type>Parking Reimbursement</Type>
              <StartDate>2016-01-01T00:00:00</StartDate>
              <EndDate>2016-12-31T00:00:00</EndDate>
              <CarrierPlanCode />
              <CarrierPlanTypeCode />
              <PolicyNumber />
              <IsIssueAgePlan>false</IsIssueAgePlan>
              <IsPostTax>false</IsPostTax>
              <PlanMapping />
              <IsSelfBill xsi:nil="true" />
              <IsSelfFunded>false</IsSelfFunded>
              <PlanIdentifier>ab8ec95d-5ded-40c7-b101-02f84cbf3db6</PlanIdentifier>
            </Plan>
            <Plan>
              <CompanyIdentifier>TEST1_FLEX</CompanyIdentifier>
              <Carrier />
              <PlanName>Transit Reimbursement 2016</PlanName>
              <Benefit>Transit Reimbursement</Benefit>
              <Type>Transit Reimbursement</Type>
              <StartDate>2016-01-01T00:00:00</StartDate>
              <EndDate>2016-12-31T00:00:00</EndDate>
              <CarrierPlanCode />
              <CarrierPlanTypeCode />
              <PolicyNumber />
              <IsIssueAgePlan>false</IsIssueAgePlan>
              <IsPostTax>false</IsPostTax>
              <PlanMapping />
              <IsSelfBill xsi:nil="true" />
              <IsSelfFunded>false</IsSelfFunded>
              <PlanIdentifier>10406ead-0472-454a-b7e7-ab140859cb2c</PlanIdentifier>
            </Plan>
            <Plan>
              <CompanyIdentifier>TEST1_FLEX</CompanyIdentifier>
              <Carrier>Unspecified Carrier</Carrier>
              <PlanName>2017 HRA</PlanName>
              <Benefit>Consumer Directed Health</Benefit>
              <Type>Healthcare Reimbursement Account</Type>
              <StartDate>2017-01-01T00:00:00</StartDate>
              <EndDate>2017-12-31T00:00:00</EndDate>
              <CarrierPlanCode />
              <CarrierPlanTypeCode />
              <PolicyNumber>3345</PolicyNumber>
              <IsIssueAgePlan>false</IsIssueAgePlan>
              <IsPostTax>false</IsPostTax>
              <PlanMapping />
              <IsSelfBill xsi:nil="true" />
              <IsSelfFunded>false</IsSelfFunded>
              <PlanIdentifier>6ffa6dcf-59e2-4d0e-a5ec-c28ab864a3a8</PlanIdentifier>
            </Plan>
            <Plan>
              <CompanyIdentifier>TEST1_FLEX</CompanyIdentifier>
              <Carrier />
              <PlanName>2017 LPFSA</PlanName>
              <Benefit>Limited Purpose FSA</Benefit>
              <Type>Limited Purpose FSA</Type>
              <StartDate>2017-01-01T00:00:00</StartDate>
              <EndDate>2017-12-31T00:00:00</EndDate>
              <CarrierPlanCode />
              <CarrierPlanTypeCode />
              <PolicyNumber>1123</PolicyNumber>
              <IsIssueAgePlan>false</IsIssueAgePlan>
              <IsPostTax>false</IsPostTax>
              <PlanMapping />
              <IsSelfBill xsi:nil="true" />
              <IsSelfFunded>false</IsSelfFunded>
              <PlanIdentifier>2d7dba8f-aedc-477e-a49d-d2801b3e79c5</PlanIdentifier>
            </Plan>
            <Plan>
              <CompanyIdentifier>TEST1_FLEX</CompanyIdentifier>
              <Carrier />
              <PlanName>Flexible Spending Account 2017</PlanName>
              <Benefit>Flexible Spending Account</Benefit>
              <Type>Flexible Spending Account</Type>
              <StartDate>2017-01-01T00:00:00</StartDate>
              <EndDate>2017-12-31T00:00:00</EndDate>
              <CarrierPlanCode />
              <CarrierPlanTypeCode />
              <PolicyNumber>123456</PolicyNumber>
              <IsIssueAgePlan>false</IsIssueAgePlan>
              <IsPostTax>false</IsPostTax>
              <PlanMapping />
              <IsSelfBill xsi:nil="true" />
              <IsSelfFunded>false</IsSelfFunded>
              <PlanIdentifier>5259cd33-872a-46ee-8870-143fc79018b1</PlanIdentifier>
            </Plan>
            <Plan>
              <CompanyIdentifier>TEST1_FLEX</CompanyIdentifier>
              <Carrier>HSA Bank</Carrier>
              <PlanName>HSA 2017</PlanName>
              <Benefit>Consumer Directed Health</Benefit>
              <Type>Healthcare Savings Account</Type>
              <StartDate>2017-01-01T00:00:00</StartDate>
              <EndDate>2017-12-31T00:00:00</EndDate>
              <CarrierPlanCode />
              <CarrierPlanTypeCode />
              <PolicyNumber />
              <IsIssueAgePlan>false</IsIssueAgePlan>
              <IsPostTax>false</IsPostTax>
              <PlanMapping />
              <IsSelfBill xsi:nil="true" />
              <IsSelfFunded>false</IsSelfFunded>
              <PlanIdentifier>6d6176c7-2d1b-489d-a173-2bca69c96d3e</PlanIdentifier>
            </Plan>
          </Plans>
          <Employees>
            <Employee>
              <ExternalEmployeeId>19151</ExternalEmployeeId>
              <CompanyIdentifier>TEST1_FLEX</CompanyIdentifier>
              <SSN>123456789</SSN>
              <FirstName>Wilson</FirstName>
              <MiddleName />
              <LastName>Abner</LastName>
              <Gender>M</Gender>
              <DOB>1965-06-15T00:00:00</DOB>
              <MaritalStatus>Married</MaritalStatus>
              <Address1>21 Wilson Lane</Address1>
              <Address2 />
              <City>gaithersburg</City>
              <State>MD</State>
              <County />
              <ZIP>20850</ZIP>
              <Country />
              <Email>wabner@123.com</Email>
              <Phone>(301) 123-9922</Phone>
              <PhoneExtension xsi:nil="true" />
              <HireDate>2011-11-15T00:00:00</HireDate>
              <HiredOn>2010-03-02T17:18:00</HiredOn>
              <Salary>137000.00</Salary>
              <SalaryEffectiveDate>2013-04-23T00:00:00</SalaryEffectiveDate>
              <LastSalaryReviewDate xsi:nil="true" />
              <PayFrequency>24</PayFrequency>
              <WeeklyHours>40</WeeklyHours>
              <EmployeeNumber />
              <PayrollID />
              <EmploymentStatus>Active</EmploymentStatus>
              <LeaveStart xsi:nil="true" />
              <LeaveEnd xsi:nil="true" />
              <JobTitle>Director of Operations</JobTitle>
              <RetiredDate xsi:nil="true" />
              <TerminationDate xsi:nil="true" />
              <TerminatedOn xsi:nil="true" />
              <Class>Full Time / Salaried</Class>
              <Department>Operations</Department>
              <Division>Bel Air</Division>
              <Office>Bel Air</Office>
              <PayrollGroup>Sample Payroll BW24</PayrollGroup>
              <Disabled xsi:nil="true" />
              <TobaccoUser>true</TobaccoUser>
              <TobaccoSignatureDate>2011-12-16T00:00:00</TobaccoSignatureDate>
              <USCitizen xsi:nil="true" />
              <DisabledStartDate xsi:nil="true" />
              <DisabledEndDate xsi:nil="true" />
              <ClassEffectiveDate xsi:nil="true" />
              <Created>2010-01-15T15:50:55.283</Created>
              <DemographicLastModified>2017-01-06T10:36:57.78</DemographicLastModified>
              <HrisComplete>true</HrisComplete>
              <Dependents>
                <Dependent>
                  <SSN>100200300</SSN>
                  <SequenceNumber>1</SequenceNumber>
                  <FirstName>Tori</FirstName>
                  <MiddleName />
                  <LastName>Abner</LastName>
                  <Relationship>Spouse</Relationship>
                  <Gender>F</Gender>
                  <DOB>1972-02-21T00:00:00</DOB>
                  <AddressSameAsEmployee>true</AddressSameAsEmployee>
                  <Address1>21 Wilson Lane</Address1>
                  <Address2 />
                  <City>gaithersburg</City>
                  <State>MD</State>
                  <County />
                  <ZIP>20850</ZIP>
                  <Country />
                  <Phone />
                  <Student>false</Student>
                  <Disabled>false</Disabled>
                  <TobaccoUser>false</TobaccoUser>
                  <TobaccoSignatureDate xsi:nil="true" />
                  <DisabledStartDate xsi:nil="true" />
                  <DisabledEndDate xsi:nil="true" />
                  <StudentStartDate xsi:nil="true" />
                  <StudentEndDate xsi:nil="true" />
                  <Created>2010-01-18T15:16:16.06</Created>
                  <LastModified>2013-04-24T14:57:09.813</LastModified>
                </Dependent>
                <Dependent>
                  <SSN>111222333</SSN>
                  <SequenceNumber>2</SequenceNumber>
                  <FirstName>Todd</FirstName>
                  <MiddleName />
                  <LastName>Abner</LastName>
                  <Relationship>Child</Relationship>
                  <Gender>M</Gender>
                  <DOB>2009-07-06T00:00:00</DOB>
                  <AddressSameAsEmployee>true</AddressSameAsEmployee>
                  <Address1>21 Wilson Lane</Address1>
                  <Address2 />
                  <City>gaithersburg</City>
                  <State>MD</State>
                  <County />
                  <ZIP>20850</ZIP>
                  <Country />
                  <Student>false</Student>
                  <Disabled>false</Disabled>
                  <TobaccoUser xsi:nil="true" />
                  <TobaccoSignatureDate xsi:nil="true" />
                  <DisabledStartDate xsi:nil="true" />
                  <DisabledEndDate xsi:nil="true" />
                  <StudentStartDate xsi:nil="true" />
                  <StudentEndDate xsi:nil="true" />
                  <Created>2010-01-18T15:17:01.81</Created>
                  <LastModified>2010-01-18T15:17:01.81</LastModified>
                </Dependent>
              </Dependents>
              <Enrollments>
                <Enrollment>
                  <EnrollmentType>Current</EnrollmentType>
                  <Plan>Medical Flexible Spending Account 2014</Plan>
                  <GroupNumber>123456</GroupNumber>
                  <PolicyNumber>123456</PolicyNumber>
                  <Benefit>Flexible Spending Account</Benefit>
                  <Type>Flexible Spending Account</Type>
                  <PlanStarts>2014-01-01T00:00:00</PlanStarts>
                  <PlanEnds>2014-12-31T00:00:00</PlanEnds>
                  <CoverageLevel />
                  <StartDate>2014-07-04T00:00:00</StartDate>
                  <EnrolledOn>2014-07-03T14:46:05</EnrolledOn>
                  <EndDate xsi:nil="true" />
                  <EndedOn xsi:nil="true" />
                  <SignDate>2014-07-03T00:00:00</SignDate>
                  <EmployeeCost xsi:nil="true" />
                  <EmployerCost xsi:nil="true" />
                  <DefinedContributionAmount xsi:nil="true" />
                  <PlanCost xsi:nil="true" />
                  <BenefitAmount xsi:nil="true" />
                  <StartReason>Loss of dependent child status (36 months)</StartReason>
                  <PCPEffectiveDate xsi:nil="true" />
                  <AttainedAge>false</AttainedAge>
                  <CarrierPlanCode />
                  <EmployeeCovered>true</EmployeeCovered>
                  <SpouseCovered>false</SpouseCovered>
                  <DomesticPartnerCovered>false</DomesticPartnerCovered>
                  <ChildrenCovered>0</ChildrenCovered>
                  <CafeteriaData>
                    <CurrentElection>3000.00</CurrentElection>
                    <PerPayAmount>250.00</PerPayAmount>
                    <PayPeriods>12</PayPeriods>
                    <EmployerPerPayAmount>0.00</EmployerPerPayAmount>
                    <EmployerAnnualAmount>0.00</EmployerAnnualAmount>
                    <OriginalStartDate>2014-07-04T00:00:00</OriginalStartDate>
                    <AnnualAmount>3000.00</AnnualAmount>
                  </CafeteriaData>
                  <Created>2014-07-03T14:45:59.65</Created>
                  <LastModified>2014-07-03T14:45:59.65</LastModified>
                  <DependentEnrollees />
                  <Beneficiaries />
                  <PlanMapping />
                  <EnrollmentMapping />
                  <PlanIdentifier>2881cce8-c4d5-4db6-9723-f45f3fba991f</PlanIdentifier>
                </Enrollment>
              </Enrollments>
              <CobraEnrollments />
              <FutureSalaries />
              <MappedClassification>TEST1_FLEX</MappedClassification>
              <AnnualBenefitSalary xsi:nil="true" />
              <EmployeeMapping />
              <AnnualBenefitSalaryEffectiveDate xsi:nil="true" />
            </Employee>
            <Employee>
              <ExternalEmployeeId>226483</ExternalEmployeeId>
              <CompanyIdentifier>TEST1_FLEX</CompanyIdentifier>
              <SSN>556655668</SSN>
              <FirstName>Kyle</FirstName>
              <MiddleName />
              <LastName>Adams</LastName>
              <Gender>M</Gender>
              <DOB>1969-01-01T00:00:00</DOB>
              <MaritalStatus>Married</MaritalStatus>
              <Address1>1 street</Address1>
              <Address2 />
              <City>Gaithersburg</City>
              <State>MD</State>
              <County />
              <ZIP>20878</ZIP>
              <Country>US</Country>
              <Email>kadams@dundermifflin.com</Email>
              <Phone>(123) 090-8909</Phone>
              <PhoneExtension xsi:nil="true" />
              <HireDate>2013-12-01T00:00:00</HireDate>
              <HiredOn>2014-01-07T00:00:00</HiredOn>
              <Salary>100000.00</Salary>
              <SalaryEffectiveDate>2014-12-01T00:00:00</SalaryEffectiveDate>
              <LastSalaryReviewDate xsi:nil="true" />
              <PayFrequency>24</PayFrequency>
              <WeeklyHours>40</WeeklyHours>
              <EmployeeNumber />
              <PayrollID />
              <EmploymentStatus>Active</EmploymentStatus>
              <LeaveStart xsi:nil="true" />
              <LeaveEnd xsi:nil="true" />
              <JobTitle>Director of Business Development</JobTitle>
              <RetiredDate xsi:nil="true" />
              <TerminationDate xsi:nil="true" />
              <TerminatedOn xsi:nil="true" />
              <Class>Full Time / Salaried</Class>
              <Division>Gaithersburg/Corp</Division>
              <Office>Gaithersburg</Office>
              <PayrollGroup>Sample Payroll BW24</PayrollGroup>
              <Disabled xsi:nil="true" />
              <TobaccoUser xsi:nil="true" />
              <TobaccoSignatureDate xsi:nil="true" />
              <USCitizen xsi:nil="true" />
              <DisabledStartDate xsi:nil="true" />
              <DisabledEndDate xsi:nil="true" />
              <ClassEffectiveDate xsi:nil="true" />
              <Created>2014-01-07T14:47:59.31</Created>
              <DemographicLastModified>2017-01-06T09:57:27.687</DemographicLastModified>
              <HrisComplete>true</HrisComplete>
              <Dependents>
                <Dependent>
                  <SSN />
                  <SequenceNumber>1</SequenceNumber>
                  <FirstName>Sarah</FirstName>
                  <MiddleName />
                  <LastName>Adams</LastName>
                  <Relationship>Spouse</Relationship>
                  <Gender>F</Gender>
                  <DOB>1970-01-01T00:00:00</DOB>
                  <AddressSameAsEmployee>true</AddressSameAsEmployee>
                  <Address1>1 street</Address1>
                  <Address2 />
                  <City>Gaithersburg</City>
                  <State>MD</State>
                  <County />
                  <ZIP>20878</ZIP>
                  <Country />
                  <Phone />
                  <Student>false</Student>
                  <Disabled>false</Disabled>
                  <TobaccoUser xsi:nil="true" />
                  <TobaccoSignatureDate xsi:nil="true" />
                  <DisabledStartDate xsi:nil="true" />
                  <DisabledEndDate xsi:nil="true" />
                  <StudentStartDate xsi:nil="true" />
                  <StudentEndDate xsi:nil="true" />
                  <Created>2014-01-07T14:48:48.147</Created>
                  <LastModified>2014-01-07T14:48:48.147</LastModified>
                </Dependent>
                <Dependent>
                  <SSN />
                  <SequenceNumber>2</SequenceNumber>
                  <FirstName>Daisy</FirstName>
                  <MiddleName />
                  <LastName>Adams</LastName>
                  <Relationship>Child</Relationship>
                  <Gender>F</Gender>
                  <DOB>2010-01-01T00:00:00</DOB>
                  <AddressSameAsEmployee>true</AddressSameAsEmployee>
                  <Address1>1 street</Address1>
                  <Address2 />
                  <City>Gaithersburg</City>
                  <State>MD</State>
                  <County />
                  <ZIP>20878</ZIP>
                  <Country />
                  <Phone />
                  <Student>false</Student>
                  <Disabled>false</Disabled>
                  <TobaccoUser xsi:nil="true" />
                  <TobaccoSignatureDate xsi:nil="true" />
                  <DisabledStartDate xsi:nil="true" />
                  <DisabledEndDate xsi:nil="true" />
                  <StudentStartDate xsi:nil="true" />
                  <StudentEndDate xsi:nil="true" />
                  <Created>2014-01-07T14:49:03.287</Created>
                  <LastModified>2014-01-07T14:49:03.287</LastModified>
                </Dependent>
              </Dependents>
              <Enrollments>
                <Enrollment>
                  <EnrollmentType>Current</EnrollmentType>
                  <Plan>Medical Flexible Spending Account 2014</Plan>
                  <GroupNumber>123456</GroupNumber>
                  <PolicyNumber>123456</PolicyNumber>
                  <Benefit>Flexible Spending Account</Benefit>
                  <Type>Flexible Spending Account</Type>
                  <PlanStarts>2014-01-01T00:00:00</PlanStarts>
                  <PlanEnds>2014-12-31T00:00:00</PlanEnds>
                  <CoverageLevel />
                  <StartDate>2014-01-01T00:00:00</StartDate>
                  <EnrolledOn>2014-01-07T15:50:05</EnrolledOn>
                  <EndDate xsi:nil="true" />
                  <EndedOn xsi:nil="true" />
                  <SignDate>2014-01-07T00:00:00</SignDate>
                  <EmployeeCost xsi:nil="true" />
                  <EmployerCost xsi:nil="true" />
                  <DefinedContributionAmount xsi:nil="true" />
                  <PlanCost xsi:nil="true" />
                  <BenefitAmount xsi:nil="true" />
                  <StartReason>New Hire</StartReason>
                  <PCPEffectiveDate xsi:nil="true" />
                  <AttainedAge>false</AttainedAge>
                  <CarrierPlanCode />
                  <EmployeeCovered>true</EmployeeCovered>
                  <SpouseCovered>false</SpouseCovered>
                  <DomesticPartnerCovered>false</DomesticPartnerCovered>
                  <ChildrenCovered>0</ChildrenCovered>
                  <CafeteriaData>
                    <CurrentElection>312.00</CurrentElection>
                    <PerPayAmount>12.00</PerPayAmount>
                    <PayPeriods>26</PayPeriods>
                    <EmployerPerPayAmount>0.00</EmployerPerPayAmount>
                    <EmployerAnnualAmount>0.00</EmployerAnnualAmount>
                    <OriginalStartDate>2014-01-01T00:00:00</OriginalStartDate>
                    <AnnualAmount>312.00</AnnualAmount>
                  </CafeteriaData>
                  <Created>2014-01-07T15:50:01.227</Created>
                  <LastModified>2014-01-07T15:50:01.227</LastModified>
                  <DependentEnrollees />
                  <Beneficiaries />
                  <PlanMapping />
                  <EnrollmentMapping />
                  <PlanIdentifier>2881cce8-c4d5-4db6-9723-f45f3fba991f</PlanIdentifier>
                </Enrollment>
              </Enrollments>
              <CobraEnrollments />
              <FutureSalaries />
              <MappedClassification>TEST1_FLEX</MappedClassification>
              <AnnualBenefitSalary xsi:nil="true" />
              <EmployeeMapping />
              <AnnualBenefitSalaryEffectiveDate xsi:nil="true" />
            </Employee>
          </Employees>
          <CorporationType>LLC</CorporationType>
        </Company>

      </Companies>
    </Data>
```

Comment: Could you add a sample xml?

Comment: And please update the title so that is says what your code is doing not your question about it.

Comment: @t3chb0t I have added sample XML

Comment: Have you considered actually parsing the document using XML serializers or Data Contracts? I always cringe when I see these kinds of XDocument constructs outside of very, very simple or very generic XML usage.

Comment: @jessehouwing: Devil's advocate: this example may be the easiest example of a bunch of XML conversions. If other more complex conversions warrant a manual XDocument construct, then it's acceptable to use the same method for a simple conversion, in the interest of maintaining code consistency.

Comment: As @t3chb0t suggests a XSLT can be used to transform or extract the data prior to ingestion. But there is something to say for consistency.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not reading your `Xml` 1:1 into a data object but you use a lot of conditions there to get alternative elements like here:

> ```
> EmployerPerPayAmount = (string)x.Element("CafeteriaData") != null ? (string)x.Element("CafeteriaData").Element("EmployerPerPayAmount") : (string)x.Element("HSAData").Element("EmployerPerPayAmount"),
> ```

I suggest reading about [XSLT - Transformation](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_transformation.asp) first. With this you can write a script that will transform your input `Xml` to another `Xml` that exactly matches your classes.

Comment: Let me try this

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use the [XML Schema definition tool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/xml-schema-definition-tool-xsd-exe) to turn your xsd definition into c# classes. Then, all you need is to use .Net native xml serializer to serialize and deserializer your data.

Instead of adding code. I'll follow you to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364253/how-to-deserialize-xml-document) which has a great explanation on how to modeling xml serializable classes and how to use the xml serializer

Comment: Quote from wiki: _It can be used by programmers to verify each piece of item content in a document. They can check if it adheres to the description of the element it is placed in._ - This won't help you to import the file into a class if that class has a different structure like it does here. You'll still need to transform it to something else.

Comment: @t3chb0t: Agree, but conversion between two classes (strongly typed) is notably easier than conversion between an XML structure and a class with a different structure ([stringly typed](http://wiki.c2.com/?StringlyTyped)). This answer may not be complete, but its suggestion still dramatically improves the existing code quality.